# What is causing my app to crash each time the button pressed?

Tags: java, android, textview, settext

After I enter the credit hours and grade for each course then press the calculate the GPA button, my app just crashes.

I have tried debugging and found all the logic is working good up until the set text for my textview. Then it crashes and does not display the GPA below the button.

```
package com.example.gpa_tejadaa4_calculator;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText ch1,ch2,ch3,ch4,ch5;
    private EditText g1,g2,g3,g4,g5;
    private Button gpa_calc;
    private TextView result;
    //private int credit_sum = 0;
    //private int grade_sum = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Credit Hours
        ch1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.C_H1);
        ch2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.C_H2);
        ch3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.C_H3);
        ch4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.C_H4);
        ch5 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.C_H5);

        //Grades
        g1= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.L_G1);
        g2= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.L_G2);
        g3= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.L_G3);
        g4= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.L_G4);
        g5= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.L_G5);

        //Button
        gpa_calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        //Result
        result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

        gpa_calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                calculateGPA();
            }
        });
    }

    public void calculateGPA() {

        double quality_points = 0;
        double credit_sum = 0;
        double gpa=0;
        double chour1 = Double.valueOf(ch1.getText().toString());
        double chour2 = Double.valueOf(ch2.getText().toString());
        double chour3 = Double.valueOf(ch3.getText().toString());
        double chour4 = Double.valueOf(ch4.getText().toString());
        double chour5 = Double.valueOf(ch5.getText().toString());

        String l1 = String.valueOf(g1.getText());
        String l2 = String.valueOf(g2.getText());
        String l3 = String.valueOf(g3.getText());
        String l4 = String.valueOf(g4.getText());
        String l5 = String.valueOf(g5.getText());

        double[] creditArray = new double[]{chour1, chour2, chour3, chour4, chour5};
        String[] gradeArray = new String[]{l1,l2,l3,l4,l5};
        credit_sum = chour1+chour2+chour3+chour4+chour5;

        for(int i=0; i<gradeArray.length; i++){

            if (gradeArray[i].equals("A")){

                quality_points += (creditArray[i] * 4);

            }
            else if (gradeArray[i].equals("B")){

                quality_points += (creditArray[i] * 3);
            }
            else if (gradeArray[i].equals("C")){

                quality_points += (creditArray[i] * 2);
            }
            else if (gradeArray[i].equals("D")){

                quality_points += (creditArray[i] * 1);
            }
            else if (gradeArray[i].equals("F")){

                quality_points += (creditArray[i] * 0);
            }

        }

        gpa = (quality_points/credit_sum);
        String str = Double.toString(gpa);
        result.setText(str);
    }}
```

```
2019-02-15 22:14:57.347 14693-14693/? I/daa4_calculato: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2019-02-15 22:14:57.527 14693-14693/? W/daa4_calculato: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2019-02-15 22:14:58.474 14693-14693/com.example.gpa_tejadaa4_calculator W/daa4_calculato: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
2019-02-15 22:14:58.483 14693-14693/com.example.gpa_tejadaa4_calculator I/chatty: uid=10086(com.example.gpa_tejadaa4_calculator) identical 10 lines
2019-02-15 22:14:58.483 14693-14693/com.example.gpa_tejadaa4_calculator W/daa4_calculato: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
2019-02-15 22:14:58.575 14693-14693/com.example.gpa_tejadaa4_calculator I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
2019-02-15 22:14:59.642 14693-14706/com.example.gpa_tejadaa4_calculator I/daa4_calculato: Background concurrent copying GC freed 6297(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 54% free, 1297KB/2MB, paused 14.095ms total 327.337ms
2019-02-15 22:14:59.794 14693-14693/com.example.gpa_tejadaa4_calculator W/daa4_calculato: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
2019-02-15 22:14:59.813 14693-14693/com.example.gpa_tejadaa4_calculator W/daa4_calculato: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
2019-02-15 22:15:00.449 14693-14693/com.example.gpa_tejadaa4_calculator W/daa4_calculato: JNI critical lock held for 17.117ms on Thread[1,tid=14693,Runnable,Thread*=0xe82dc000,peer=0x74473f50,"main"]
2019-02-15 22:15:00.807 14693-14693/com.example.gpa_tejadaa4_calculator D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
2019-02-15 22:15:01.401 14693-14718/com.example.gpa_tejadaa4_calculator I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-02-15 22:15:01.402 14693-14718/com.example.gpa_tejadaa4_calculator I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2019-02-15 22:15:01.402 14693-14718/com.example.gpa_tejadaa4_calculator I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2019-02-15 22:15:01.402 14693-14718/com.example.gpa_tejadaa4_calculator D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
2019-02-15 22:15:01.439 14693-14718/com.example.gpa_tejadaa4_calculator D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xe23582a0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
2019-02-15 22:15:01.469 14693-14718/com.example.gpa_tejadaa4_calculator D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe23582a0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe2303730)
2019-02-16 00:26:44.489 14693-14693/com.example.gpa_tejadaa4_calculator I/Choreographer: Skipped 54 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2019-02-16 00:26:44.579 14693-14718/com.example.gpa_tejadaa4_calculator D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe23582a0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe2303730)
2019-02-16 00:26:45.337 14693-14718/com.example.gpa_tejadaa4_calculator I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=1747ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=45140893368546, Vsync=45141793368510, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=45141795801750, AnimationStart=45141796075440, PerformTraversalsStart=45141800459550, DrawStart=45141816295150, SyncQueued=45141885063390, SyncStart=45141887514590, IssueDrawCommandsStart=45141887629200, SwapBuffers=45142416409300, FrameCompleted=45142643449160, DequeueBufferDuration=739000, QueueBufferDuration=2893000, 
2019-02-16 00:26:45.376 14693-14693/com.example.gpa_tejadaa4_calculator I/Choreographer: Skipped 50 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2019-02-16 00:26:45.506 14693-14718/com.example.gpa_tejadaa4_calculator I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=970ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=45141841971519, Vsync=45142675304819, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=45142683525380, AnimationStart=45142683649680, PerformTraversalsStart=45142684303680, DrawStart=45142686442990, SyncQueued=45142697271280, SyncStart=45142697377900, IssueDrawCommandsStart=45142697527290, SwapBuffers=45142698807910, FrameCompleted=45142812805650, DequeueBufferDuration=88000, QueueBufferDuration=1463000, 
2019-02-16 00:27:17.077 14693-14693/com.example.gpa_tejadaa4_calculator W/daa4_calculato: JNI critical lock held for 22.109ms on Thread[1,tid=14693,Runnable,Thread*=0xe82dc000,peer=0x74473f50,"main"]
2019-02-16 00:27:17.116 14693-14693/com.example.gpa_tejadaa4_calculator W/daa4_calculato: JNI critical lock held for 24.765ms on Thread[1,tid=14693,Runnable,Thread*=0xe82dc000,peer=0x74473f50,"main"]
2019-02-16 00:27:36.598 14693-14693/com.example.gpa_tejadaa4_calculator D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2019-02-16 00:27:36.601 14693-14693/com.example.gpa_tejadaa4_calculator E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.gpa_tejadaa4_calculator, PID: 14693
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.gpa_tejadaa4_calculator.MainActivity.calculateGPA(MainActivity.java:101)
        at com.example.gpa_tejadaa4_calculator.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:47)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6597)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6574)
        at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:778)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25885)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
2019-02-16 00:27:36.639 14693-14693/com.example.gpa_tejadaa4_calculator I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 14693 SIG: 9
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/L_G5"
        android:layout_width="113dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/Grade"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.87"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/C_H5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/L_G4"
        android:importantForAutofill="no" tools:targetApi="o" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/L_G4"
        android:layout_width="113dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/Grade"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.94"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/C_H4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/L_G3"
        android:importantForAutofill="no" tools:targetApi="o" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/C_H5"
        android:layout_width="114dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/credit_hours"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/c5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/C_H4"
        android:importantForAutofill="no" tools:targetApi="o" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/c5"
        android:layout_width="67dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="@string/course_5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/c4" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/c3"
        android:layout_width="67dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="@string/course_3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/c2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/C_H4"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/credit_hours"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/c4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/C_H3"
        android:importantForAutofill="no" tools:targetApi="o" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/c4"
        android:layout_width="67dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="@string/course_4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/c3" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/L_G3"
        android:layout_width="113dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/Grade"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/C_H3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/L_G2"
        android:importantForAutofill="no" tools:targetApi="o" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/C_H3"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/credit_hours"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/c3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/C_H2"
        android:importantForAutofill="no" tools:targetApi="o" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/L_G2"
        android:layout_width="112dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/Grade"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/C_H2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/L_G1"
        android:importantForAutofill="no" tools:targetApi="o" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/C_H2"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/credit_hours"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/c2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/C_H1"
        android:importantForAutofill="no" tools:targetApi="o" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/c2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="21dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="@string/course_2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/c1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/c1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
        android:text="@string/course_1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/C_H1"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/credit_hours"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/L_G1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/c1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:importantForAutofill="no" tools:targetApi="o" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/L_G1"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/Grade"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/C_H1"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:importantForAutofill="no" tools:targetApi="o" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="78dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:onClick="calculateGPA"
        android:text="@string/compute_gpa"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/C_H5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="66dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="170dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="170dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="175dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="175dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="119dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

expected output: calculated GPA 
Actual Results : App crashes

Comment: can you show logcat message?

Comment: Please share the logcat so that we can see what the issue is?

Comment: Show us the logs.

Comment: Based on your View names you've been using, any chance the id for your Button isn't `R.id.button` but `R.id.gpa_calc`?

Comment: I checked and they are matched up

Comment: It worked fine on me. I used the following value: Course 1 = 23 Grade = A, Course 2 = 24 Grade = B, Course 3 = 18 Grade = C, Course 4 = 21 Grade = A, Course 5 = 15 Grade = A. I removed the `onClick` attribute in the xml for the result button because you already declared it on code so it'll just be redundant to do that.

Comment: how can I initialize result? I am new to java and confused about how I would do this. I tried the link above but it did not help too much.

Comment: Solved it. I had two XML files the second one (v26) did not have same attributes and was giving me the exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText ch1,ch2,ch3,ch4,ch5;
    private EditText g1,g2,g3,g4,g5;
    private Button gpa_calc;
    private TextView result;
     Double final =0;
    //private int credit_sum = 0;
    //private int grade_sum = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Credit Hours
        ch1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.C_H1);
        ch2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.C_H2);
        ch3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.C_H3);
        ch4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.C_H4);
        ch5 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.C_H5);

        //Grades
        g1= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.L_G1);
        g2= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.L_G2);
        g3= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.L_G3);
        g4= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.L_G4);
        g5= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.L_G5);

        //Button
        gpa_calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        //Result
        result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.result);

        gpa_calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

               final= calculateGPA();
              result.setText(final.toString());

            }
        });
    }

    public double calculateGPA() {

        double quality_points = 0;
        double credit_sum = 0;
        double gpa=0;
        double chour1 = Double.valueOf(ch1.getText().toString());
        double chour2 = Double.valueOf(ch2.getText().toString());
        double chour3 = Double.valueOf(ch3.getText().toString());
        double chour4 = Double.valueOf(ch4.getText().toString());
        double chour5 = Double.valueOf(ch5.getText().toString());

        String l1 = String.valueOf(g1.getText());
        String l2 = String.valueOf(g2.getText());
        String l3 = String.valueOf(g3.getText());
        String l4 = String.valueOf(g4.getText());
        String l5 = String.valueOf(g5.getText());

        double[] creditArray = new double[]{chour1, chour2, chour3, chour4, chour5};
        String[] gradeArray = new String[]{l1,l2,l3,l4,l5};
        credit_sum = chour1+chour2+chour3+chour4+chour5;

        for(int i=0; i<gradeArray.length; i++){

            if (gradeArray[i].equals("A")){

                quality_points += (creditArray[i] * 4);

            }
            else if (gradeArray[i].equals("B")){

                quality_points += (creditArray[i] * 3);
            }
            else if (gradeArray[i].equals("C")){

                quality_points += (creditArray[i] * 2);
            }
            else if (gradeArray[i].equals("D")){

                quality_points += (creditArray[i] * 1);
            }
            else if (gradeArray[i].equals("F")){

                quality_points += (creditArray[i] * 0);
            }

        }

        gpa = (quality_points/credit_sum);
        String str = Double.toString(gpa);
       return gpa;
    }}
```

Comment: Attempted your edits and now it won't compile. How can a keyword be set to a value?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be related to your question but I fixed your layout. You can still improve it of course.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/L_G5"
        android:layout_width="113dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/Grade"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/C_H5"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/C_H5"
        tools:targetApi="o" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/L_G4"
        android:layout_width="113dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/Grade"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/C_H4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/C_H4"
        tools:targetApi="o" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/C_H5"
        android:layout_width="114dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/credit_hours"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/c5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/c5"
        tools:targetApi="o" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/c5"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="@string/course_5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/c4" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/c3"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="@string/course_3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/c2" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/C_H4"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/credit_hours"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/c4"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/C_H3"
        android:importantForAutofill="no" tools:targetApi="o" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/c4"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="@string/course_4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/c3" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/L_G3"
        android:layout_width="113dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/Grade"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/C_H3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/C_H3"
        tools:targetApi="o" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/C_H3"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/credit_hours"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/c3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/c3"
        tools:targetApi="o" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/L_G2"
        android:layout_width="112dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/Grade"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/C_H2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/C_H2"
        tools:targetApi="o" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/C_H2"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/credit_hours"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/c2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/c2"
        tools:targetApi="o" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/c2"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="21dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="@string/course_2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/c1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/c1"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="112dp"
        android:text="@string/course_1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/C_H1"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/credit_hours"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/c1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/c1"
        tools:targetApi="o" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/L_G1"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/Grade"
        android:importantForAutofill="no"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/C_H1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/C_H1"
        tools:targetApi="o" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="78dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="@string/compute_gpa"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/C_H5" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/result"
        android:layout_width="66dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="170dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="175dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="119dp"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```